# Laravel Edit Answer and Question connection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm coding a quiz app and I have an edit-function where I can edit the different questions. Now I'm trying to connect the answers edit to the questions edit, but I don't know how.

I'm a beginner in Laravel, so it would be nice if you could help me.
My code is below. If you need anything else please let me know.

My web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProductController;
use App\Http\Controllers\MainController;
use App\Http\Controllers\QuizController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');

Route::get('dashboard', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');

Route::get('quiz/create', 'App\Http\Controllers\QuizController@create');
Route::post('quiz', 'App\Http\Controllers\QuizController@store');
Route::get('quiz/{quiz?}', 'App\Http\Controllers\QuizController@show')->name('quiz/show');

Route::get('quiz/{quiz}/questions/create', 'App\Http\Controllers\QuestionController@create');
Route::post('quiz/{quiz}/questions', 'App\Http\Controllers\QuestionController@store');
Route::delete('quiz/{quiz}/questions/{question}', '\App\Http\Controllers\QuestionController@destroy');
Route::get('question/{question}', '\App\Http\Controllers\QuestionController@edit')->name('question/edit');
Route::patch('question/{question}', '\App\Http\Controllers\QuestionController@update')->name('question/update');

Route::get('startquiz/{quiz}-{slug}', 'App\Http\Controllers\StartQuizController@show');
Route::post('startquiz/{quiz}-{slug}', 'App\Http\Controllers\StartQuizController@store');
```

My edit blade

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <body>


        <h1>Edit Question</h1>
        <form action="{{ route('question/update',$question->id) }}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            @method('PATCH')

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="question">Question</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="question" value="{{ $question->name }}"placeholder="Enter Question">
                                <small id="questionHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Type in your edited question.</small>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        @foreach($answers as $answer)
                            {{ dd($answer) }}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="question">Answer {{ $loop->iteration }}</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer{{ $loop->iteration }}" value="{{ $answer->name }}">
                                <small id="answerHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Type in your edited answer.</small>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

My Question Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Answer;
use App\Models\Question;
use App\Models\Quiz;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class QuestionController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Quiz $quiz) {
        return view('question.create', compact('quiz'));
    }

    public function store(Quiz $quiz) {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'question.question' => 'required',
            'answers.*.answer' => 'required',
        ]);

        $question = $quiz->questions()->create($data['question']);
        $question->answers()->createMany($data['answers']);

        return redirect('/quiz/'.$quiz->id);
    }

    public function destroy(Quiz $quiz, Question $question) {
        $question->answers()->delete();
        $question->delete();

        return redirect($quiz->path());
    }
    public function edit(Question $question) {
        $answers = $question->answers;
        return view('quiz.edit', compact('question', 'answers'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Question $question, Answer $answer) {
        $question->update($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('quiz/show', ['quiz' => $question->quiz])
                        -> with('success', 'Question updated successfully');
    }
}
```

My Question Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Question extends Model
{
    protected $guarded =[];
    protected $fillable = ['question'];

    public function quiz() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Quiz::class);
    }

    public function answers() {
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
    }

    public function responses() {
        return $this->hasMany(QuizResponses::class);
    }
}
```

My dd

```
App\Models\Question {#1364 ▼
  #guarded: []
  #fillable: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "questions"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:5 [▶]
  #original: array:5 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
}
```

Answer Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Answer extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function question() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
    }

    public function responses() {
        return $this->hasMany(QuizResponses::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: `dd()` within foreach loop of answers should have an instance of `App\Models\Answer` while in the dump above it is showing `App\Models\Question`

Answer (score 1):

because you must compact in edit function $answer too :

```
return view('quiz.edit', compact('question','answer'));
```

Comment: I changed it, but now I get another error. You can see it in my question above.

Comment: When you are editing a question, it can have answers right? So in that case you should not be assigning a new instance of Answer class to $answers variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are providing a question in your controller

```
  return view('quiz.edit', compact('question'));
```

but are not providing an answer variable which you are using in your blade:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer" value="{{ $answer->name }}" placeholder="Enter your new answer">
```

Comment: I added answer to compact, but now I get another error. You can see it above

Comment: You probably need to do something like $answer = $question->answer() in your controller function. At least if you have defined a relation like that between question and answer that would work. The place to learn about relations is https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations

Comment: I did it and my Question Model has a relation to Answer. You can see this in my Question Model above. Now I get the error ```Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$name (View: /home/vagrant/code/quizapp/resources/views/quiz/edit.blade.php)```

Comment: @Leonie113m Probably the error arises as you are trying to get `value="{{$answer->name}}"` in blade snippet within foreach loop for answers. While your migration shows that `answers` table doesn't have a `name` column. Probably it should have been `value="{$answer->answer}}"`

Answer (score 0):

In your `edit` function, `answer` variable does not exist because `compact()` function contains variables and their values. To solve your issue, you have to create `answer` object with values from database. I will take the code below as a sample.

```
use App\Models\Answer;
...
    public function edit(Question $question) {
       $answers = $question->answers();

       return view('quiz.edit', compact('question', 'answers'));
    }
```

**Edit**

In `edit()` function, you replace `$answer` by `$answers`. In `blade.php`, you could use the following code.

```
@foreach($answers as $answer)
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="question">Answer {{$loop->iteration}}</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer{{$loop->iteration}}" value="{{ $answer->name }}" placeholder="Enter your new answer">
        <small id="answerHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Type in your edited answer.</small>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224766/discussion-on-answer-by-than-lng-laravel-edit-answer-and-question-connection).

Answer (score 0):

Since the context is editing an existing Question, it is very likely that the Question being edited already has Answers (or not).

So the controller edit method should be

```php
    public function edit(Question $question) {
        $answers = $question->answers;
        
       return view('quiz.edit', compact('question', 'answers'));
    }
```

And in the blade (form) you can iterate over the answers associated with the question.

```
 <div class="col-xs-12">
     @foreach($answers as $answer)
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="answer{{ $loop->iteration }}">Answer {{ $loop->iteration }}</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer{{ $loop->iteration }}" value="{{ $answer->answer }}">
             <small id="answerHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Type in your edited answer.</small>
         </div>
     @endforeach
 </div>
```

Probably the error for undefined property `$name` arises because the migration for the `answers` table you posted in one of the comments shows that `answers` table does not have `name` column - you should probably change `value="{{$answer->name}}"` to `value="{{$answer->answer}}"` in the blade snippet